# return action on key hit

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uitextfield

I have a textfield:

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchbar: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
```

I want that after I hit enter on keyboard/ return key on simulator keyboard, it generate an action. I did not want use uibutton with IBAction.

Here is my code :
on viewdidload I write:

```
self.searchbar.delegate = self;
```

after that I write the function:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.scrollView.endEditing(true)
    searchbar.resignFirstResponder()
    searchbtn.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    return true
}
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    getWeb()
}
func getWeb(){
    //keyword
    self.searchbar.delegate = self
    let keyword = self.searchbar.text
    let lowercasekeyword = keyword!.lowercaseString
    let a = "http://"
    let b = lowercasekeyword
    let keywords = a + b
    let url = NSURL (string: keywords);
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    webView.loadRequest(requestObj);
}
```

But the webView did not load with the website that I type.
How to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

You are just adding target to your search button when you hit enter in the keyboard.

Try with the below code for `textFieldShouldReturn`

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.scrollView.endEditing(true)
    searchbar.resignFirstResponder()
    getWeb()
    return true
}
```